# Raspberry Pi Benchmark

Tags: parallel-processing, raspberry-pi, benchmarking

I am currently a high school student who is doing a mentorship project in Hampton University. My group members and I are using Raspberry Pis to study parallel processing and super computers. Our project involves altering the clocking speed, number of Pis used, and quality of the SD Card inserted to find the processing speed of the Raspberry Pi cluster. 
The problem I am facing is that I want to code my own benchmark software similar to LINPACK program to be able to test the processing speed. I am currently taking multivariable calculus and linear algebra, and I learned the computer languages java and c. I know how to operate in linux in pretty rudimentary level. Will it be possible for me to create a benchmark program? Or do I not have enough knowledge of the field? If so, can I get the steps involved in completing it? I am willing to learn new things and eager to do so. I am used to learning these things in a tutorial as well. And I forgot to mention. I have approximately three months to complete it, so the program does not have to be too complicated. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Have a look at my RPi benchmarks. The codes are available for anyone to play with. These include Linpack and Livermore Loops, the original supercomputer benchmark.

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/Raspberry%20Pi%20Benchmarks.htm

Comment: Thank you for the website I am looking through it, and it think it will be a lot of help. Also, does this benchmark also work for clusters or is it only for single pi?

Comment: There are a quite a few different benchmarks from that site, that run on a single Pi. These include a number of multithreading tests that would use multiple CPU cores (up to 8), if only the Pi had them. For a cluster, you need to be able to communicate between processors. I suppose I would do this as in my LAN benchmark and probably drive the cluster by a PC front end, just as they used to do with the real thing, using a mainframe. You will find details of Pi clusters by Googling for them.